# Como abrir uma nova aba com javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Olá! 
Tenho essa função aqui:
`function mostrar(id){
            window.location = "visualizar.php?id=" + id;}`

Que eu chamo quando o usuário clica num `<a href="javascript:mostrar(id)" target="_blank"></a>`

E eu quero que eu abre uma nova aba e não feche a atual.(Não guia, como um pop-up) mas parece que o `target="_blank"` não está funcionando como normalmente. Tem alguma coisa pra se fazer na função javascript pra fazer isso?

Comment: e qual o problema de colocar a url no atributo href?

Comment: O código é um pouco mais complexo que isso

Comment: Mais complexo que: `<a href="visualizar.php?id=5" target="_blank"></a>`

Ou usando variáveis em php: `<a href="visualizar.php?id=$id" target="_blank"></a>`

Comment: É que tem uma consulta em banco de dados, mas eu vou tentar simplificar desse jeito

Comment: A bom, devia falar sobre isso, porque você deixou bem claro que está com problemas para abrir uma nova aba com Javascript, em um link `<a>`, não especificou mais nada!

Comment: Nossa, realmente dava pra simplificar mesmo hahahah. Valeu amigo!